# Display DB values in a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am displaying values from a database into a dropdownlist. but I am unable to get the corresponding values into the DDL.

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                dt1 = bll.getnewid(TextBox1.Text);

                    if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {

                        Session["pid"] = dt1.Rows[0]["NewidColumn"].ToString();
                        Session["email"] = dt1.Rows[0]["EmailID"].ToString();
                        Session["gender"] = dt1.Rows[0]["Gender"].ToString();
                        Session["mobile"] = dt1.Rows[0]["MobileNo"].ToString();
                        Session["country"] = dt1.Rows[0]["Country"].ToString();
                        Session["state"] = dt1.Rows[0]["State"].ToString();
                      }
```

and I am displaying like this

```
   DropDownList1.Text = Session["country"].ToString();
            DropDownList2.Text = Session["state"].ToString();
```

I am able to get the country and state values in the datatable. but I am unable to display them in the DDL.

Answer (score 1):

```
DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(Session["country"].ToString()); 
DropDownList2.Items.Add(new ListItem(Session["state"].ToString());
```

Comment: Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to 'System.Web.UI.Control' 

I am getting an error like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(Session["country"].ToString()); 
DropDownList2.Items.Add(new ListItem(Session["state"].ToString());
Dropdownlist2.databind();
Dropdownlist1.databind();
```

Comment: When i do like this i am getting the values but in country ddl it is showing -select a country- instead the country name,how to display country name directly.

Comment: DropDownList2.Items.Add(new ListItem(Session["ID"].ToString(),Session["countryname"].ToString());

Comment: What is session["ID"] here?? I have not assigned anything to it probably  Object reference not set to an instance of an object error will occur.

Comment: it means you have to add counrty id to session ..before use

Comment: Add this statement `DropDownList2.SelectedIndex = 0;`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15713/discussion-between-anant-dabhi-and-chandra-sekhar)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `SelectedValue` or `SelectedIndex` property of your dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
   DropDownList1.Items.Add("yourvalue");
   DropDownList1.Items.Add(Session["country"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code :

```
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(Session["country"].ToString(), "0"));
DropDownList1.DataBind();

DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(Session["state"].ToString(), "0"));
DropDownList2.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the need of using sessions ..?
Instead try this..hope it works.
After this line of code  (dt1 = bll.getnewid(TextBox1.Text);)
use this two lines instead of sessions.

```
DropDownList1.DataSource=dt1;
DropDownList1.DataTextField="Country";
DropDownList1.DataValueField="Country";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
DropDownList2.DataSource=dt1;
DropDownList2.DataValueField="Country";
DropDownList2.DataValueField="Country";
DropDownList2.DataBind();
```

Comment: here country and state are the names of the columns in the data table dt1. make sure column names match to the dt1.

Comment: I am catching the country and state values and displaying in the another page so i am using session.

Comment: do u mean to say the selected country and state or the entire list of countries and states..?

Comment: I am populating the values from DB which are selected by the use and displaying them in the DDL not the list.

Comment: From the code you have written you will get only the first row of the dt in sessions .Instead can't u store the dt in session and typecast it to datatable while accessing the values ?

Comment: I mean session["Sourcetable"]=dt; Dropdownlist.datasource=(DataTable)Session["Sourcetable"]; USe the datatable similarly where ever needed. If possible use a common method to get the values instaeda of storing in sessions because people generally dont recomment sessions unless required.