# Display DB values in a Dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display DB values in a dropdownlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088358/display-db-values-in-a-dropdownlist)

I am fetching DB values and displaying them in the Dropdown list. I have country and state drop down lists:

```
DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(Session["country"].ToString()));
DropDownList2.Items.Add(new ListItem(Session["state"].ToString()));
```

I am unable to show the DB values in the DDL. I am getting --select a state--
in the state Dropdown list how to show the DB values in the Dropdown list?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Select a state" >Select a state</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="value 1" >Maharastra</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="value 2" >Goa</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="value 3" >Kashmir</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

i am cacthing the DB values here and sending them to the next page

```
  if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                dt1 = bll.getnewid(TextBox1.Text);

                    if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {

                        Session["country"] = dt1.Rows[0]["Country"].ToString();
                        Session["state"] = dt1.Rows[0]["State"].ToString();
```

Comment: Is the problem that they are not added, or that they are added, but they are not the default value?

Comment: It's not the duplicate of the previous question as you can see i can get the country and state names in the datatable but i cant display the names as i am getting the -select state- in the DDL how to show exact state name in the DDL??

Comment: `Select a state` is obviously your default value and if your ddlist doesn't show anything else, you haven't followed my advice at all. I really can't help you if you don't cooperate. If you can't explain, maybe try to show what do you have at the moment and what is it supposed to look.

Comment: This is what i am getting http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/15/12927645.jpg/

Comment: If you can't figure out why the -select state- appear in the DDL, you have hardcoded it in you .aspx... If you have no idea what you have done, maybe start to learn the basics.

Comment: As i am updating the user values after logged in,so i have to give the other options to the user so i am displaying the other listitem values in the DDL i hope you got it?

Comment: Just updated my answer. It's not by no means a final product, but it should give you an idea and push you into a right direction. If that doesn't answer your question though, I give up.

Comment: @Chandrasekhar no sorry I don't get it at all. Check my answer or the well explained walther one. If you don't get this to works, I suspect (regarding the others questions you asked) you have not a correct backgroung for programming and you are just seeking the perfect answer to fit your code.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you must somehow bind your ddlist to the db results. Looks like this:

```
ddlist1.DataSource = MyDBAccessClass.GetSomeValues();
ddlist1.DataBind();
```

Based on more comments... I'll have to play a little roulette and guess what's your intentions. Your code has multiple problems and you've obviously some issues explaining yourself.

If I understood you correctly, you have 2 dropdownlists. You want to populate one with countries and based on the selection, populate the second dropdownlist.

The basic principle looks like this:

DataAccessClass.cs

```
public class DataAccessClass
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetCountries()
    {
        // access the database and retrieve all the values
        // returns IEnumerable (a list of items)
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetStates(string selectedCountry)
    {
        // access the database and retrieve all the corresponding states
        // linq2sql: var states = from o in db.States
        //                        where o.country = selectedCountry
        //                        select o;
        // returns IEnumerable (a list of items)
    }
}
```

YourPage.aspx

```
<asp:DropDownList id="ddlistCountries" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" /><br />
<asp:DropDownList id="ddlistStates" runat="server" />
```

YourPage.aspx.cs

```
public partial class YourPage
{
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         ddlistCountries.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddlist_SelectedIndexChanged);
    } 

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!isPostBack)
        {
            PopulateCountries();
            ddlistStates.Enabled = false; // no country selected yet!
        }
    }

    protected void PopulateCountries()
    {
        ddlistCountries = DataAccessClass.GetCountries();
        ddlistCountries.DataBind();   
        ddlist.Items.Insert(0, "Select a country");
    }

    void ddlist_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlistCountries.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
             ddlistStates.DataSource = DataAccessClass.GetStates(ddlistCountries.SelectedValue);
             ddlistStates.DataBind();
             ddlistStates.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ddlistStates.Items.Clear();
            ddlistStates.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

If you can't understand this, either go back to basics or forget about programming altogether.

Comment: I am getting the values from the DB and i am passing them to the next page so i am using session

Comment: @Chandrasekhar, doesn't matter how you get your values, you need to databind them to the ddlist either way. (unless you iterate + assign the collection manually)

Comment: Even though i do like this i am getting the result like this  

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/15/12927645.jpg/

and i have to display the corresponding state names in the DDL also??

Comment: @Chandrasekhar, your code and explanation doesn't make any sense at all. Let me show you how to do it properly, because this is just... Ridiculous at best!

Comment: this is what i have done to populate countries DDL with states so i know how to do it,if you cant understand my question better you dont answer it no issues anyway.

Comment: @Chandrasekhar, no, you stick your values in a completely ridiculous way to your session and then trying to achieve something, that OBVIOUSLY no one here understands. But yea, I guess we're those with problems to explain a problem, not you. I give up, you obviously know it better than us and it's an utter waste of time trying to help.

Answer (score 3):

```
DropDownList2.DataSource = {your data source}; 
DropDownList2.DataTextField = "text column name"; 
DropDownList2.DataValueField = "data column name of id"; 
DropDownList2.DataBind();
```

You need to set your data source to the DDL, then set which values to display, then bind it.

Comment: Can you tell what is "text column name" ??

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the dropdownlist like this :

```
ddl.DataSource = YourDBSource.Get();
ddl.DataBind();
```

you can then decide what to be displayed here with :

```
ddl.DataTextField = ...;

or 

ddl.DataValueField = ...;
```

First of all, there is no reason to build your listItem in the .aspx page because you will populate your ddl programmatically.

Secondly I don't know what you mean by 'i am cacthing the DB values here and sending them to the next page'. Just fill the dataSource with the appropriate query on you DB.

If you want to perform more easy filtering / wahtever you want, try to use Linq2SQL.

Additionally, you need to perform this databinding in the *Page_Load()* like this :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ddlErreur.DataSource = ...;
            ddlErreur.DataTextField = ...;
            ddlErreur.DataBind();
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit?

Comment: What i have to set for the datatextfield of DDL?

Comment: Maybe read the documentation of the DropDownList control ? 5sec with google : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist_properties ; and please read my entire answer and try yourself a bit to make it works, you have all the informations here.